# Play Pause Video inside a div on a slider

Tags: jquery, html, html5-video

I have a site which imitates a presentation where an image and a video are both moved to the next when Next button is clicked. Inversely for the Back button.

The problem is that I am struggling to play video when the Next Button is clicked. How can I play a video on the next page (and pause the video on the current page) when next button is clicked and similarly do it for the previous page when the Back button is clicked?

Here is what I did.

### Code

```
  <div class="example1">
        <video  class="example1" width="220" height="180" controls  false>
          <source src="./files/videos/myvideo.mp4" type="video/mp4">
        </video>

        <div style="clear:float ;height: 10px;"></div>
        <span class="presented">Presented by: </span>
        <a href="#" class="presenter black">A Presenter</a>
        <span class="slide-count">Slide <strong>3 of 6</strong></span> 
  </div>
```

### JS

```
$(document).ready(function(e) {


    var $curr = $( "#start" );
    $curr.css( "height" , "" );

    $( ".back" ).click(function() {
      $curr = $curr.prev();
      var styles = {
          display: "block"
        };

        var default_styles = {
          display: "none"
        };
      $( "div.example" ).css( default_styles );
      $curr.css( styles );
    });


    $( ".forward" ).click(function() {

      $curr = $curr.next();
    var styles = {
          display: "block"
        };

        var default_styles = {
          display: "none"
        };
      $( "div.example" ).css( default_styles );
      $curr.css( styles );
    });


    var $curr1 = $( "#start1" );
    $curr1.css(  "height" , "" );

    $( ".back" ).click(function() {
      $curr1 = $curr1.prev();
      var styles = {
          display: "block"
        };

        var default_styles = {
          display: "none"
        };
      $( "div.example1" ).css( default_styles );
      $curr1.css( styles );
    });


    $( ".forward" ).click(function() {

      $curr1 = $curr1.next();
    var styles = {
          display: "block"
        };

        var default_styles = {
          display: "none"
        };
      $( "div.example1" ).css( default_styles );
      $curr1.css( styles );

      //$curr1.children('video').play();
      //$curr1.children('video').attr({'autoplay':'true'});


    });






});
```

### What I tried in jQuery and didn't work

```
  $curr1.children('video').play();
  $curr1.children('video').attr({'autoplay':'true'});
  $("#example2 video.example1").play();
```

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to call `play()` on a jQuery object. You need to call it on the native video DOM element instead. You can use the jQuery `.get()` function for that:

```
$curr1.children('video').get(0).play();
```

or

```
$curr1.children('video')[0].play();
```